# map an object android

Tags: android

Hi im trying to create an array of the keys/values in a Object from a map. i have a function in a global actions class that formulates a url by passing in Objects with values in breaking them up to form a string to add to my url. does anyone know how to map an object and extract all the keys/values to a string?

heres what i have so far

```
public final static void startAPICallRequest(Context activityContext, String request, String apiLocation, Object postVarsObj, JSONObject getVarsObj){

            long unixTimeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L;

            Log.v("globals", "getVarsObj: " + getVarsObj);




                if(getVarsObj != null){

             Map map = (Map) getVarsObj;
             for (Object key : map.keySet()) {
                 ((Object) getVarsObj).toString();

            }

             Log.v("globals","map=" + map);

        }

        }
```

Comment: And the problem is...?

Comment: its saying my syntax is wrong so im wanting to know what the correct syntax is to do this?

Comment: And can you show which error you're getting?

Comment: i have edited my codethe error im getting is its not logging anything

Comment: ... You said: *"its saying my syntax is wrong"* Which error are you getting?

Comment: Map is a raw type. References to generic type Map<K,V> should be 
  parameterized

Answer (score 0):

Try using parameters when you declare your `Map`

`Map<K,V> map = new Map<K,V>();`

Where `K` is the data type you want to use for your `key` and `V` is the data type you will use for your `value` in the `Map`. Looks like your value will be an `Object` and your key maybe a `String`. Then add your objects to the `Map` with `map.put(k,v)`

Comment: Also he can't print a map like `Log.v("globals","map=" + map);`

Comment: @m0skit0 hows about instead of telling me what i havent done right hows about you actually give some constructive feedback i want to map an object and i dont know how i have given it a go and its not right so if you know how to do that id appriciate the help? im just trying to learn i know im doing it wrong thats why im on here asking for help

Comment: That is correct, sir, thank you. I think you can but you won't get any results that you want

Comment: I don't think he meant to sound as harsh as he did. It was a bit confusing on where you were getting an error and why but I took a stab because I knew you weren't declaring it correctly. We are all friends here :)

Comment: @LukeBatley we're **volunteers** here. I don't have to help you; I'm trying anyway, but I definitely can't help you if you don't provide enough details. Your code has several conceptual errors. IMHO you're trying to do stuff that's way beyond your knowledge in Java. Start with more simple stuff.

Comment: @LukeBatley did you try my suggestion?